# What happens with the bytes written in Android AudioTrack write method in Mode_Stream

Tags: android, buffer, audiotrack

I am using the `AudioTrack` Object in Stream Mode to build a ring buffer.
I am using the `OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener` listener with `onPeriodicNotification` to get to know, when to refill the buffer.

First: This call is not very precise.

When I meassure the time, there is a jitter of several miliseconds between the periodic calls. Why?

Second:
Lets say I am getting the `onPeriodNotification` around 100 samples before the buffer runs out of samples. What happens if I fill the buffer now with the write function call. Does it write the bytes to the queue of the `AudioTrack` buffer - so it appends it to the end?

I am asking those questions, because I realised, that there is always a huge jitter between my sound.

Lets say I have a short sound, like a horn of a car. Its length is 100ms.
I want it to repeat it exactly each second.

I wanted to fill the audiotrack buffer with zeros (silence) for 900ms and than write the horn sound and repeat it all over.

Comment: just use a background thread and call `write` method in a tight loop in `WRITE_BLOCKING` mode

Comment: Hi @pskink, thanks for replying.
Why do you suggest write_blocking?

I am still using a asyncTask. Maybe I have to replace it.

Comment: so if you are writing in `doInBackground` why not to use WRITE_BLOCKING?

Comment: Yes, I was playing around with write_blocking and non_blocking...

I still dont know, why I get more jitter if I am using stream_mode and filling the buffer myself than using static_mode and looping the sound

Comment: Its not audible - its just when you record the data and check the data in audacity - spectogram you can see the jitter +-2ms which is below 1ms using static_mode with loop

Comment: But @pskink could you please clarify, that the bytes written to the buffer are appended?